# Startup script fails to run

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to create an instance on google compute engine from the command line and using the *--metadata-from-file* flag. The body of the local file (written as .txt, changed to .sh) passed in is as follows-

```
#! /bin/sh
gsutil cp -R gs://<bucketname> .
```

As far as I can tell this should download the specified bucket from google storage when the instance starts (the same command entered while SSHed after start works). When I list directories from SSH window, the bucket hasn't been downloaded.

Can anyone see what might be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at /var/log/startupscript.log , does it contain any useful error message?

Comment: Are you aware that `'.'` means the root directory(`/`)? I have created an instance with that script and it worked for me but as I told you I have a folder in the root called /<bucket_name> where I have all my folders and objects. If it doesn't work, check the log that @PaoloPasetti has pointed.

Comment: Or check `cat /var/log/daemon.log | grep startup` on debian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For startup scripts, confusion can be avoided if you use only absolute paths. Notably, '.' in a startup script (root) is not the same as '.' when you run ls via ssh (your home directory).

Comment: I launched the instance from the api and it gives me the message _"Your current active account [accountname] does not have any valid credentials."_  when i try `gsutil cp` which is why the script isn't working. Do you know how I would solve this?

Comment: There are two ways to address this. One is to create a VM with a service account attached. Unfortunately you can't add one after the VM is created. The other is to create a new service account on the Cloud Console, copy its key into your VM, and use 'gcloud auth activate-service-account' to activate it manually. From then on, gsutil should work without needing any more credentials.

Comment: do you know how i would create an instance with a service account attached and is it possible from the API? I can't find it in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [service account](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#service_account_names) upon creation of the instance for Google Cloud Storage (GCS), this way the instance will be allow to upload to GCS using this account

Comment: I put it in another question to make things easier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931207/instance-cant-copy-to-and-from-storage