# gsutil on a Google Compute Engine VM can't use service account authentication with a key file

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm launching an instance from the google .net API and despite my best efforts I can't get it to copy anything to or from storage. Currently I'm authenticating with a developer console service account like this:-

```
string ServiceAccountEmail = "blahblah@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(ServiceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = new[] { ComputeService.Scope.Compute, ComputeService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl }
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

var cs = new ComputeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    ApplicationName = "appname",
    HttpClientInitializer = (Google.Apis.Http.IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer)credential,
});


Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.Instance newinst = new Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.Instance();
newinst.Name = "generatedinstance";
newinst.MachineType = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/projectid/zones/zone/machineTypes/n1-standard-1";

Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.AttachedDisk ad = new Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.AttachedDisk();
ad.AutoDelete = true;
ad.Boot = true;
ad.Type = "PERSISTENT";
ad.InitializeParams = new Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.AttachedDiskInitializeParams();
ad.InitializeParams.DiskName = "newdisk";
ad.InitializeParams.SourceImage = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/projectid/global/images/customimage";
ad.InitializeParams.DiskType = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/projectid/zones/zone/diskTypes/pd-standard";
ad.Mode = "READ_WRITE";
newinst.Disks = new List<Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.AttachedDisk>();
newinst.Disks.Add(ad);

Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.NetworkInterface ni = new Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.NetworkInterface();
ni.Network = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/projectid/global/networks/default";
ni.AccessConfigs = new List<Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.AccessConfig>();
ni.AccessConfigs.Add(new Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.AccessConfig
{
    Type = "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT",
    Name = "External NAT",
});
newinst.NetworkInterfaces = new List<Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.NetworkInterface>();
newinst.NetworkInterfaces.Add(ni);
var start = new Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.Metadata.ItemsData();
start.Key = "startup-script";
start.Value = "*startup script* includes gsutil cp which won't work without service account attached";
newinst.Metadata = new Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.Metadata();
newinst.Metadata.Kind = "compute#metadata";
newinst.Metadata.Items = new List<Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.Metadata.ItemsData>();
newinst.Metadata.Items.Add(start);
newinst.ServiceAccounts = new List<Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.ServiceAccount>();

//var sa = new Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.ServiceAccount();|with this section
//sa.Email = "blahblah@developer.gserviceaccount.com";      |the instance won't
//sa.Scopes = new[] { ComputeService.Scope.Compute,         |start. (An equivalent
    ComputeService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl };           |is found in instance
//newinst.ServiceAccounts.Add(sa);                          |start REST request)

var instinsert = new InstancesResource.InsertRequest(cs, newinst, "projectid", "zone");
var insertresponse = instinsert.Execute();
```

The message I get when I try to use `gsutil cp` is *"You do not currently have an active account selected."*. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Do you get an account and project name from "gcloud config list" command ?

Comment: @PaoloP. just a project name

Comment: Maybe you have to do "gcloud auth login" and authenticate with your credentials. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKAY! Problem solved. The part I was getting wrong was the bit commented out in the question-

```
var sa = new Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.ServiceAccount();
sa.Email = "blahblah@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
sa.Scopes = new[] { ComputeService.Scope.Compute,
    ComputeService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl };
newinst.ServiceAccounts.Add(sa);
```

I needed the email for the main service account for the developer console in this section rather than the same service account I used to create the credentials but don't ask me why. Point is the instance launches and gsutil is now happily copying away.
Thanks for your time and help everyone!
Ross

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `gcloud auth activate-service-account blahblah@developer.gserviceaccount.com --key-file path_to_key.p12` to tell the Cloud SDK (including gsutil) about your service account.

Comment: He doesn't need to run the gcloud auth activate-service-account, since he's trying to create an instance using the API and having a startup script in the VM

Comment: I tried activating the service account from a separate instance but it only means i can use it for THAT instance. I can't activate it on the current instance as I can't upload the key file

Answer (score 0):

As per the code provided, I can see that the [original](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service_account) example has

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

I notice you are missing the '@'in your code. I'm not very familiar with .Net. I have tested these examples in [python](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/api/python-guide#addinganinstance) and this [one](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-getting-started-python). When creating my instance I added the service account for GCS and the file is uploaded correctly.

Comment: sorry, the @ is there in the actual code, i forgot to include it in the question

Comment: do i need to add my service account with the scopes to the "service accounts" field of the insert request? it seems to do so in the rest api equivalent found in the developer console but, when i do, the instance doesn't start